# xjc :GConf Error: Failed to launch configuration server: Failed to fork child process (Cannot allocate memory)

Tags: xhtml, jaxb, xjc

I would like to unmarshal this xhtml in to Java objects. I have downloaded the dtd and using the following command to unmarshal it.

The dtd is http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd

And the command I am using is:

`[/opt/downloads/test/Original_dtd]# xjc -dtd xhtml-mobile10.dtd
parsing a schema...
GConf Error: Failed to launch configuration server: Failed to fork child process (Cannot allocate memory)`

How can I unmarshal the dtd ? Or is there any way to convert the dtd to xsd and unmarshal it ? will it be easier to transfer the dtd to xsd for unmarshalling using xjc?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the memory for your JVM:

`[.../Original_dtd]# XJC_OPTS="-Xmx512m" xjc -dtd xhtml-mobile10.dtd`